# Passwords are not md5 or changing despite different entries

Tags: mysql, passwords, md5, login-script

For some reason MySQL is putting all passwords as the same even after md5 and using the `password('$md5_password')`.

Let's say the password is `abc123` the password stored in mysql is `11ab5e691dcc370b`. But when I try to save a password of `frogs` the password stored is `11ab5e691dcc370b`, which is the same. I have the same script on other databases and is working flawlessly.

The above would explain why no one is logging in unless I hard set the `11ab5e691dcc370b` password. Then others can login.

The mysql user has full rights.

Comment: Can you add some more of the code around that point, my current idea is that the code actually just ends up setting all the passwords to the same thing.

Comment: I think that it takes the $md5_password as string not as variable can you show more code ?

Comment: Whats your insert query?

Comment: See http://forum.hashkiller.com/index.php?topic=4447.0 `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` hashes to `11ab5e691dcc370b` (I don't know what hash function though). I assume you're always passing in `d41...` but note that `d41...` is an MD5 hash of an empty string. Maybe you need to try something other than `$md5_password = md5('')`?

Answer (score 2):

I used Google to reverse `11ab5e691dcc370b`. [It seems to be the hash of `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`](http://forum.hashkiller.com/index.php?topic=4447.0), which is an MD5 of a blank string.

You might want to check the code that actually calls `md5`.

Comment: todda is correct. `SELECT CAST(OLD_PASSWORD(MD5('')) AS CHAR) ;` produces: `'11ab5e691dcc370b'`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PHP based on the $md5_password in your question

Use double quotes or remove them completely.

```
md5($password);
```

If you use single quotes it will literally hash the string $password

```
md5('$password');
```

See this page on string literals http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: See my comment - it looks like he's hashing a blank string. So he's not passing in `'$password'`.